# NSFileManager's ubiquityIdentityToken always returning null, even when logged in

Tags: objective-c, macos, icloud, osx-mavericks

My Mac application in Xcode has recently begun exhibiting strange symptoms when attempting to access iCloud. There haven't been any changes to my provisioning profiles, code signing identities, etc.

However, when running this code:

```
id token = [fileManager ubiquityIdentityToken];
NSLog(@"Token is: %@", token);
NSURL *iCloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSLog(@"iCloud URL is: %@", iCloudURL);
```

The output is:

```
2013-10-28 08:17:12.372 MyApp[21101:303] Token is: (null)
2013-10-28 08:17:12.373 MyApp[21101:303] iCloud URL is: (null)
```

Which I find extremely strange, especially considering I *am* actually signed into iCloud on this machine. To be sure, I ran a quick test with Calendar, adding an event on an iPhone and ensuring that it showed up on the Calendar on my Mac.

But I was under the impression that `[fileManager ubiquityIdentityToken];` would return whether the user was logged into iCloud, regardless of whether your entitlements, code signing, etc. was properly configured - indicating that it's less an issue on my end, and more an issue of the system's ability to return this value.

I have tried logging out (and back in) to iCloud, and have ensured that "Documents & Data" is enabled in the iCloud settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by upgrading from the original Mavericks GM (build 13A598) to the official release (build 13A603.)